# Oracle 11g: How to track origin of a dataset?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am currently analyzing a database and happened to find two datasets whose origin is unknown to me. The problem is that they shouldn't even be in there...

I checked all insertion scripts and I'm sure that these datasets are not inserted. They are also not in the original dumpfile.

The only explanation I can come up with at the moment is, that they are inserted via some procedure call in the scripts.

Is there any way for me to track down the origin of a single dataset?

best regards,
daZza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can,

assuming your database is running in archivelog mode you can use logminer to find which transactions did the inserts. See [Using LogMiner to Analyze Redo Log Files](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/logminer.htm#SUTIL019) It will take some serious time but that might be worth it.